# How to use jquery ajax with a form submission

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Changed the code to this now. Form is located in subscribe.php which in included into the index page.

```
<form class="subscribe" id="email" method="get">
    <input class="email" id="emailaddress" name="email" type="text" placeholder="EXAMPLE@EMAIL.COM" required>
    <input class="button" type="submit" id="emailSub" value="Subscribe">
</form>
<div id="subResult"></div>
```

Jquery is at bottom of the index page

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#emailSub').click(function() {
        var email = $('#emailaddress').val();
        alert(email);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'script', //<-Data Type for AJAX Requests(xml | html | script | json)
            url: 'checksub.php',
            data: {
                'e': email
            },
            success: function(result) {
                $("#subResult").html(result);
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Checksub page is this now for testing.

```
<?php include 'admin/includes/db_connection.php'; ?>
<?php 
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_GET['e']);
echo "test string:";
echo $email;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you should to change dataType? try it:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'html', //<-Data Type for AJAX Requests(xml | html | script | json)
    url: 'checkemail.php',
    data: {
        'e': email
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $("#subResult").html(result);
    }
});
```

and

```
<input class="button" type="submit" id="emailSub" value="Subscribe">
                              ^ HERE
```

should be :

```
<input class="button" type="button" id="emailSub" value="Subscribe">
```

because of `submit` is submiting form and refreshing the page.. so jquery not work..

[Specifying the Data Type for AJAX Requests](http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests)

Comment: Can i test the ajax itself first. I have checkemail.php echoing 'test' and nothing is showing up

Comment: your jquery code is correct.. i guess the problem is in `php` file, test the php file..

Comment: Its all changed im using checksub.php but I have everything changed appropriatly

Comment: Yes jquery is linked in. I edited the code so you can see all the pages with code now. I can alert the email I enter successfully so jquery is working

Comment: so change the php file to `<?php echo "test"; ?>` and try again, if error : then error is in your included file..

Comment: Did that but nothing, because im using ajax do i need to put the action in on the form?

Comment: Well theres all my code at the top. Checksub is now just echoing "test"; and nothing is appearing under my form. is there a fail function so i can check if the ajax success isnt working?

Comment: test this : `<form class="subscribe" id="email" method="get" action="checksub.php">`  (add action attribute to your form)

Comment: and `<input class="button" type="button" id="emailSub" value="Subscribe">` because the submit refreshing the page..

Comment: and your `dataType='html'` i tested, all is work.. and edited mu answer

Answer (score 3):

Are you preventing the default click event from firing submit?

```
$('#emailSub').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var email = $('#emailaddress').val();
    $.ajax({url:"checkemail.php?e="+email,success:function(result){
        $("#subResult").html(result);
    }});
})
```

Comment: I now have this  $('#emailSub').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var email = $('#emailaddress').val();
      $.post({url:"checksub.php", {e:email},function(result){
       $("#subResult").html(result);
   }});
  })

Comment: Great!  I didn't catch that.  You can use $.post or alternatively you can manually serialize the form $.ajax({url:"checksub.php", data:$('#email').serialize(),type: 'POST',success:function(result){
        $("#subResult").html(result);
    }});

Comment: Are you using checkemail.php or checksub.php? Your form shows it uses action="subscribe.php"